# Where is this scene originate from in Episode 5 of nichijou?

Tags: tropes, nichijou

What is this thing that Mio's cloud refers to?

And what does this text on the screen mean (The text on the screen, it's like an old Japanese font-style) ?

> "**15:40  1-Q in front of the podium**"

Based from the word "sunk", is that like boat or something ?

[image]

Relevant video on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-1-k11Utk5A&index=95&list=PLkdHUAEWslpj0KVZ1IFVOfxhjgWNChf52), check at 0:39.

Comment: The text on the screen indicates that at 3:40 PM, in front of the podium in class 1-Q (Mio's class), Naganohara Mio was "sunk" in the same way a ship would be sunk, yes. I don't recall the context of this scene, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this scene Mio is being referred to as a boat that exploded, or was hit by a bomb (of embarrassment :P) and sunk. The image intended as a visual pun based off the combination of:

a mushroom cloud (from explosion) + Mio's head/signature blue hair
[image]

The text on the screen furthers this as it refers to the time and location Mio was sunk in a similar way that one might talk about a ships time and location when it was sunk.

Comment: well nichijou sure so hyperbolic in every episode, but did the cloud refers to something ? The text on the screen, it's like an old japanese font-style so i thought they trying to parodying something but i don't know what is it... well i am not sure about that...

Comment: The idea of blowing up a ship is general. This is not a parody of another show. The reason for old-styled text is to mimic the time when ships were likely to be bombed ie. WW2

Comment: @Gagantous Imagine a telegram for a WW2 damage report..

Comment: in the original manga, the mushroom cloud doesn't have that hair bun shape so I doubt it's supposed to be Mio

Comment: @Darjeeling I don't think that fact about the manga impacts my answer. In the manga it still symbolised Mio exploding. With or without the creative choice of her blue hair buns being added to the cloud for comedic affect